# Google analitycs see results in realtime during development

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have a website that is going to use Google analytics very intensively.
The development process is very long.
I wonder if it is possible (in order to speed up the development) to force analytics to get updated in real time, so we won't have to wait few hours to see the data in the dashboard or available in the API.
I need this only in development mode. for a small amount of data. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)
>
> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.

The [Google Analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is bound by the same data latency as the google analytics website.   There is no way to speed up this processing time this is the time it takes for Google analytics to analyze your data.

There is some data available though the [realtime api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/)  but this is extreamly limited and is only valid for about five minutes.  Due to quota limitations its also not possible to query it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to see data in GA as soon as soon Site is used and GA calls are triggered.

1. One option is to view real time report of GA. It gives you a fair understanding of both pageview and event collection
2. On the behavioral dashboard, you can generate an unsampled report. Mostly, data will be available in this report. But this service requires some tokens. If you have an enterprise account of GA then you must be having tokens to generate unsampled report. Also sometimes these report generation may take 30 mins.